# Validating spam, temporary emails and emails with invalid domains

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, c#-4.0

recently I have noticed a lot of users being registered to my site and they all use  disposable emails, temporary email addresses or fake emails to register on the site...

What I have done to partially prevent that is I added mailgun email verification which tells me whether an email is valid or not , disposable one or not...

This filtered out like 95% of the fake emails and users, however there is still a small portion of them which go "unnoticed". What I have figured out to do are following things via code:

```
 public static bool IsValidEmail(string email)
        {
            RestClient client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", "");
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
            request.Resource = "/address/validate";
            request.AddParameter("address", email);
            var res = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(client.Execute(request).Content);
            if (res.is_disposable_address || res.is_valid==false)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
```

This is one step via mailgun that I described previously... And second method to prevent spam/fake users is that I have set up manually a table in my DB with blacklisted domains to which registration won't be allowed... And the logic for that is:

```
   public static bool IsValid(string email)
    {
        using (var ctx = new myEntities())
        {
            var blacklistedProviders = ctx.BlacklistedDomains.ToList();
            foreach (var item in blacklistedProviders)
            {
                if (email.ToLower().Contains(item.DomainName.ToLower()))
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

However I don't think this will prevent them from doing more malicious stuff on the website...

I have also added google recaptcha to harden the process of registration for spammers, that does the job well too....

So my questions here are:

1. Are there any other ways that I can validate the email to see whether it is disposable or invalid email
2. What other way could I implement to prevent users from creating fake accounts?

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: One of the best protection is the link validation.

Comment: Link validation ? Could you explain it a little bit more please?

Comment: @LeBigCat I should explain, these aren't bots... These are real people with real hands coming and creating fake accounts and then reselling them,.. Not bots...

Comment: Oh ok. A litle harder then..Not sure we have a lots of tech solution for that. Could use a mobile validation too. Wont be 100% sure but i dont thinck you could reach 100%.

Comment: @LeBigCat yes that's an option as well.. I was thinking that I set up an infinite lasting cookie inside a browser from user when he registers and then prevent him  - at least to create another account from that very same browser